# Mongoose - Get model from remote

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I have a main node.js server and a server who only download files (node.js too). My problem is that all models are on the main server but the download server needs this models too. I don't have an idea how I can solve that. It is possible to "download" the models from the main server?